# Unexpected error after package my script into a exe file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exe

I have chrome browser version 113 installed on my computer, and I also have google chrome portable version 114 saved on the machine. I coded Selenium to launch the chrome portable, and it works no problem when I tested in pycharm. However, after I packed the py file into a exe file, and ran the exe file, I got an error message

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Users\whuang\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI97642\GoogleChromePortable_114.0.5735.91/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe'

looks like it don't recognize the chrome portable path I provided in the code anymore, so it was looking for the binary in the default location? Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

my code:

```
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
driver_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "chromedriver.exe")
chrome_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "GoogleChromePortable_114.0.5735.91/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe")
profile_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "GoogleChromePortable_114.0.5735.91/Data/profile/Default")
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + profile_path)
chrome_service = Service(driver_path)
chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_path
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=chrome_service)
```

[Files in the folder and command used to pack the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC867.jpg)

After the exe file been generated, I moved the chromedrive file and the chrome portable folder into the folder with the exe file. but I received the error message mentioned above if I run the exe file.

[exe folder image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdDRD.jpg)

[image for error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38f3A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I repackage the file with command 'pyinstaller -F -D --icon=pen.ico AutoSurvey.py', and it is not complaining anymore